# Artist Image Not Showing, Just Artwork of their Music

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I have a `tableView` which displays a list of artists from a user's iPod library.  The cell's image should display an image of the artist.

Currently, I get this (album artwork of a song from the artist):

[image]

When the image should show this (Music.app shows this on the same device):

[image]

This is my code for my `tableView`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MPMediaItemCollection *artistCollection = artists[indexPath.row];

    MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [[artistCollection representativeItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

    UIImage *artistImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (44, 44)];

    cell.imageView.image = artistImage;

    return cell;

}
```

I've read the class reference and I can't find anything that provides the artist's image.  Does anybody know how to get this?  Thanks!

Comment: have u tried property : MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist ???

Comment: That's an NSString though.  I tried it and it returned a SIGABRT error - `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString imageWithSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170424860'` on the line after, `UIImage *artistImage = [artwork imageWithSize: CGSizeMake (44, 44)];`